# Emails still going to Gmail & Hotmail spam after removing host from several blacklists

Tags: email-server, spam, gmail, outlook-web-app, spam-marked

As I mentioned briefly in the subject the IP address of our mail server got blacklisted a while ago. One of the sites on the server got hacked, which resulted in the addition to a couple of blacklists. The hacked site got repaired.

In the meanwhile we managed to get our IP removed from all these blacklists. So the IP is clean again for a couple of weeks already. But still our mails are sent to the SPAM folders within Gmail and Hotmail.

You can see that in the glockapps report I just ran from [here](https://shared-report.glockapps.com/tests/c496c76bdfef4944ec44283b2b236580/deliverabilty)

I did plenty of tests in several mail testers and all the authentication is fine: SPF, DKIM, DMARC is all set up correctly. Also we're not listed in any blacklists anymore. Already for a couple of weeks.

Any ideas if there are any measures that could fix this in a short time, or is the only solution just to have patience ...? It's actually quite problematic as it's my work e-mail that's hosted on this server.

Thanks

Comment: The glockapps report gave you specific recommendations regarding Gmail. You need to follow them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the recommendations like Michael suggested in the comments

- Also for Hotmail you can file a request from this [form](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportrequestform/8ad563e3-288e-2a61-8122-3ba03d6b8d75)
- And for Google you can file a request from this [form](https://support.google.com/mail/contact/msgdelivery)
- It's recommended Also if you are managing your own mail server better use a mail gateway like Proxmox mail gateway for future risk mitigation
- You can Also change the IP Assigned to sending/receiving mails to a clean one if it's available from the datacenter/service provider

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Changing the IP unfortunately isn't possible. Google Postmaster doesn't give any feedback as we're not sending enough mails for that. I'll try the other things.

Comment: U w , hope your problem disappear soon , i know mail problems are real headache